# how to uninstall a NVIDIA driver if not working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I decided to install NVIDIA drivers so it can run better but
now when I boot up into Ubuntu it loads and says

The NVIDIA GeForce G102M GPU installed in this system is supported through the NVIDIA 340.xx Legacy drivers. Please
visit http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html for more information. this GPU. The 535.129.03 NVIDIA driver will ignore Continuing probe...

I am kind of new on Ubuntu so I don't know a lot of stuff

the computer is a ASUS inspiring innovation 4gigs of ram and a core 2 duo